# Is there a safe way to use a managed field in destructor?

Tags: c#, .net, file, destructor, managed

I have a class that creates a hidden file in the constructor and keeps its `FileStream` open until `Dispose()` is called. Calling `Dispose()` closes the stream and removes the hidden file.

I need to make sure that the file is removed if the program is closed without a call to `Dispose()`. I thought I can check if it still exists and call `File.Delete(path)` if it does in the destructor but the string field that holds the file path can already be collected when the destructor is called, right?

Is there a safe way to access that field from destructor?
If not, is there another way for me to make sure that file is deleted?

Comment: Just implement the (full) IDisposable pattern, and do your cleanup in the `Dispose(bool)` method. The data you need will still be available. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx

Comment: @spender: you should post this as an answer...

Comment: @spender: You're right. I thought if the `disposing` is false that means the managed fields may already be collected and that's why the destructor calls `Dispose(false)`, that's one of my reasons for asking this question. See my comment under Henk's answer.

Comment: Make sure you know the difference between Collected and Disposed. They are very different here.

Comment: And please clarify the question: what is the 'without a call to Dispose()' scenario exactly?

Comment: @Henk: As a "without a call to dispose" scenario, think about initializing the class that I mentioned in the question and close the Console window without calling Dispose() method anywhere.

Comment: @Henk: And I know the difference between Collected and Disposed, my question was about destructor (which calls `Dispose(false)` if the dispose pattern is implemented). Managed instances (like a FileStream field) may already be collected when the destructor is called so it's not safe to interact with them. After reading your answer about the string, I thought it applies to every field so it's safe to interact with the stream (I thought the GC cleans it *after* calling the destructor) but as you stated in another comment, I got it wrong.

Comment: No, the filestream cannot have been _Collected_ but it might have been _Disposed_. The string is not IDisposable so it is always safe.

Comment: @Henk: Sorry, I don't get it. If you're talking about my class, I implement the dispose pattern and have a boolean that checks if the class is already disposed, so that piece of code never gets called if the class is already disposed. If you're talking about the field, I don't publicly expose it so I know its Dispose method is never called by code. Does GC calls Dispose methods of IDisposables? Is that why string is safe?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said _"might have been Finalized"_, that means  Dispose(false) was called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but the string field that holds the file path can already be collected when the destructor is called, right?

No. That string will still be there and safe to use.

But you'll have to maneuver carefully, closing your file first if it's still open.

> I need to make sure that the file is removed if the program is closed without a call to Dispose()

That's the big challenge. Not much guarantees here. Make sure the client code *always* calls Dispose().

Comment: If none of the fields in the class is already collected, I can check whether it's open or not. But if they are not collected, what is the point of calling `Dispose(false)` in the destructor when using the *dispose pattern*? It is not because they are already collected but because they'll be collected in a moment, I suppose?

Comment: Dispose() does not apply to strings and it is _not_ about collecting objects. It is about Disposing (= internal cleanup). Your member fields will not point to collected objects but they (the filestream) _might_ be Disposed already. So check.

Comment: The Dispose(false) is because it is a) not necessary to Dispose() members and b) not always totally safe to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can simply override the `Finalize()` method of the class you are using. As per [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx):

> The destructor implicitly calls Finalize on the base class of the object. Therefore, the previous destructor code is implicitly translated to the following code:

```
protected override void Finalize()
{
    try
    {
        // Cleanup statements...
    }
    finally
    {
        base.Finalize();
    }
}
```

When working in the `Finalize()` method, you are also assured that no fields have been "collected" yet, and thus you can safely use all of the object's fields.

Answer (score 0):

If your process will crash or be killed, the Dispose() method will not be called. You should test if the certain file is locked by some other process rather than resting if the file exists

Comment: Does the destructor gets called if the process crashes or gets killed?

Comment: No. No destructor is called, when process can not run. For example if the StackOverflowException or OutOfMemoryException  are thrown, the destructors are not called. If someone kill your process, the destructor are not called too. If computer fall in the sleep and then is directly turned of. The destructors are not called. Etc...